# How to delete APFS Volume

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, disk-volume

I am trying to delete a volume and have one whole disk left, without volumes or partitions. I played around with partitioning and deleting multiple times and now it seems, I can't do anything.

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

There is no way to delete or click the - symbol, same when I select the other one.

When I go to partition on either one I can not select anything in order to delete, I can only add a partition.

Also it says on the screenshot, that I have 5 volumes, even though I only see two.

How can I fix this?

Edit: Diskutil List Result:

[image]

View Devices:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open a Terminal application window and enter the command `diskutil list`. Post the output to your question. This will provide more information than the image you have posted. You are suppose to have 5 volumes. The Disk Utility application normally does not display all the volumes. You can not delete all the volumes on the drive that you have booted to.

Comment: @DavidAnderson added it, thx! I just want to get rid of the second volume, so I have access to the whole disk. There was a second mac installed on the second disk, which I don't need anymore. Right now I can't even access the disk at all, can't save anything to it. Maybe this is the problem, since it was bootable once?

Comment: I find this question to be confusing. I can not figure out what you are asking. I requested for you to post the output of `diskutil list`. I have made the same request from many previous users with a similar question. You are the first to post the output ***twice***. I gave the updated question a quick read and could not figure out why there are two different outputs posted. Which (if any) is correct?

Comment: Catalina separates the main volume (Macintosh HD) to System (Macintosh HD) and Data (Macintosh HD - Data). It is normal to have the two volumes on Catalina and you cannot delete it on the running OS.

Comment: If you have downgraded in-place to Mojave, things will be more complex.

Comment: @amdyes what do you mean in place? I am currently on Catalina.

Comment: @amdyes oh so this is normal? I thought I have lost about 200gb. Now I feel stupid for wasting a bounty :) If this is the answer, go ahead and anwser it.

Answer (score 1):

In Disk Utility, click on View > Show All Devices. Then you should be able to select the physical disk and re-partition it, as well as the Containers.

Comment: I tried but I have the same problem, when I go to the partition pie chart I can't select anything. I added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: Have you tried just erasing the device?

Comment: The top level device, apple ssd? Will this not erase my OS?

Comment: Yes. Maybe that's the only, or easiest, way.  You've got a backup -- because you wouldn't be messing about with disk partitions on your system disk if you didn't.

Comment: But how can I delete the device I'm using to delete the device? This can't possibly work?